# Should I override jQuery UI custom stylesheet?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I used the jQuery Theme Roller to create a theme.

When I implement a widget, such as the accordion, I see that the font sizes are out of step with my main content.  What's the correct way to deal with this?

The two options I see are:

1. Modify the jQuery custom.css.  The downside of this is that if I regenerate a theme (with the theme roller), I'll overwrite my changes.
2. Override the jQuery settings with my own style sheet.  Can't see any problems with this, except that I would be introducing jQuery's selectors into my own style sheets.

So, what's the best way to go about it?

Also, do you know of any good tutorials / how-to's on the jQuery Theme's?  Particularly styling?  (I don't seem to have any difficulty getting widgets, etc, to work, but things like changing icons on state changes can be a problem...)

Comment: I do 2 all the time, no harm done in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create your own sheet. The own real downside is you will have to download 2 stylesheets instead of 1 when rendering the page. Anything you want to change would be easiest to do in your own stylesheet. You can always "merge" and minify them later.